# Looping through Df and Merge result into a particular row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with counts as:

```
target.value_counts()

Grade
AA III    147
CD IV     143
DA II     134
BB I        4
dtype: int64
```

I want to join `BB` with `DA` so that the counts of `DA` will be `138` something like this:

```
target.value_counts()

Grade
AA III    147
CD IV     143
DA II     138
```

I tried doing this:

```
for i in ["AA I", "CD II", "DA III", "BB IV"]:
    if i == "AA I":
        target["Grade"] = target["Grade"].str.replace(i, "Grade II ")
```

I was thinking I could do `replace` then see how I can merge the rows but the output will not solve the problem.

Any better suggestion on how I could achieve this?

Comment: Simply `target["Grade"] = target["Grade"].replace("AA I", "DA II")`, without the loop

Comment: @-mozway, your solution yielded the result. regards

Comment: You're welcome @kukulu I'm not sure it's worth keeping the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Working with the data you provided after calling `target.value_counts()`...

## Set up

```py
from itertools import repeat

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# make data
target = pd.DataFrame(
    data={"Grade": [*repeat("AA II", 147),
                    *repeat("CD IV", 143),
                    *repeat("DA II", 134),
                    *repeat("BB I", 4),]}
)

print(target.value_counts())
```

```
Grade
AA II    147
CD IV    143
DA II    134
BB I       4
dtype: int64
```

## Option 1

```py
# replace on the fly within the `.groupby`
out = target.value_counts().groupby(
    lambda idx: "DA II" if idx[0] == "BB I" else idx[0]
).sum()

print(out)
```

```
AA II    147
CD IV    143
DA II    138
dtype: int64
```

## Option 2

```py
# create new column ("replaced") that replaces "BB I" with "DA II"
target["replaced"] = target.Grade.replace("BB I", "DA II")

out = target[["replaced"]].value_counts()

print(out)
```

```
replaced
AA II       147
CD IV       143
DA II       138
dtype: int64
```

References

- [`pd.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response. The values `147`, `143`, `134` and `4` are `counts` of AA; CD, DA, and BB respectively and total 428. which means there are 428 observations. so, consider AA,CD,DA,BB as the observations in `Grade` column of `target` DF. with your solution, I don't think I can not use it for further analysis

Comment: @kukulu --  Do you want to replace `DA` with `BB` and sum the counts or do something else? Your question says you want to sum them (134 + 4 = 138).

Comment: it mean any rows that have `BB I` replace it with `DA II` in the `target` DF. That what I want to achieve

Comment: I think the `target.value_counts()` output I used should not  have come in in the first place. The question would have been replacing `BBI` with `DA II`. I was thinking showing the result of `target.value_counts()` will be better than printing `428` row.